# BroadcastReceiver not catching call event on Android 8.1+

Tags: java, broadcastreceiver, retrofit, telephonymanager, android-8.1-oreo

I am working on an application with call management. To detect when a call is answered or made, I tried creating a class inheriting `BroadcastReceiver` and listening to `EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER`, `ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL` and `TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE` events.

It's working as expected in Android version below 7.0 but it's not catching a single event in version 8.1 and above.

```
public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        this.context = context;
        String stateStr = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        number = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
        System.out.println("On recieve satate");
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL)) {
            number = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER).toString();
        }

        if (number != null) {
            number = number.trim();
            number = number.replace("+91", "");
        }

        else {
            Toast.makeText(context,"UNABLE ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        geturl= SplashScreen.getURL();
        TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Service.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        operator_name = tm.getNetworkOperatorName();
        if (stateStr != null) {
            if (stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
                state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING;
                // isExist = clientDataBase.isNumberExists2(number);
                //opendialogg("","","","","");
                System.out.println(" inside  state");
                if (isExist == true) {
                    DatabaseRegistration clientDataBase1 = new DatabaseRegistration(context);
                    RegistrationSetterGetter setterGetter = new RegistrationSetterGetter();
                    setterGetter = clientDataBase1.getDataOfSingleClient2(number);
                    USERname = setterGetter.getName();
                    INDUStype = setterGetter.getIndusrtyName();
                    ORGname = setterGetter.getCompanyName();
                    Log.d("RESPONSE",USERname+"  "+INDUStype+"   "+ORGname);
                    opendialogg(operator_name, number, USERname, INDUStype, ORGname);

                } else {
                    progressBar = new ProgressBar(context);
                    getNumberDeatilsOperation(number, operator_name);
                }

            } else if (stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        sendToHost();
                    }
                }, 3000);
            }
            else if (stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
                getInitial();
                context.startService(new Intent(context, MyRecordingService.class).putExtra("initcall", datess));
            }
        }

        else if (stateStr == null) {
            System.out.println("Null State"+stateStr);
            DatabaseRegistration dbAutoSave = new DatabaseRegistration(context);
            isExist = dbAutoSave.isNumberExists2(number);
            if (isExist == true) {
                RegistrationSetterGetter setterGetter = new RegistrationSetterGetter();
                setterGetter = dbAutoSave.getDataOfSingleClient2(number);
                USERname = setterGetter.getName();
                INDUStype = setterGetter.getIndusrtyName();
                ORGname = setterGetter.getCompanyName();
                System.out.print("VALUE OF EXISTING DATA PHASE");
                Log.d("RESPONSE",USERname+"  "+INDUStype+"   "+ORGname);
                opendialogg(operator_name, number, USERname, INDUStype, ORGname);
            } else {
                Log.d("RESPONSE","");
                progressBar = new ProgressBar(context);
                getNumberDeatilsOperation(number, operator_name);

            }
            // opendialogg("","","","","");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("NOT DETECT STATE");
        }
    }
```

out side onReceive method call  sendToHost(); looks like

```
public void sendToHost() {
getSendData();
}
public void getSendData() {
        SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(mypreference,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        id_user = sharedpreferences.getString("userKey", "");
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC LIMIT 1");
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToLast();
            int number = cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
            int type = cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
            int date = cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);
            int duration = cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);
            int id = cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls._ID);
            phone = cursor.getString(number);
            phone = phone.trim();
            phone = phone.replace("+91", "");
            String callType = cursor.getString(type);
            callDate = cursor.getLong(date);
            ids = cursor.getString(id);
            datess = new SimpleDateFormat("yyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault()).format(callDate);
            callDur = cursor.getString(duration);
            dir = null;
            int dircode = Integer.parseInt(callType);
            switch (dircode) {
                case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
                    dir = "OUTGOING";
                    break;
                case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:

                    dir = "INCOMING";

                    break;
                case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
                    dir = "MISSED";
                    break;
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
    }


}
```

Manifest looks like:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"/>

 <receiver android:name=".Unused.CallReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="finishMeeting"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"/>
            </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must hold the Manifest.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS permission to receive this Intent.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL

Comment: I have already used it, forgot to mention it in code. Just edit the code